# Type downcasting can't find original method in Swift

Tags: swift, generics

I find that Swift class can't call the original method while it is done type downcasting.

AFAIK, same thing can be done in C/C++ by class pointer.

Let code talks:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func log()
}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {
}

class MyGenericClass<T>{
    init(_ t: T) {}
}

extension MyGenericClass: MyProtocol {
    func log() {
        print("MyGenericClass MyProtocol")
    }
}

extension MyGenericClass where T==Int {
    func log() {
        print("MyGenericClass<Int>")
    }
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func log() {
        print("MyProtocol")
    }
}
extension MyProtocol where Self==TestSwift.MyGenericClass<Int> {
    func log() {
        print("MyProtocol where MyGenericClass<Int>")
    }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self==MyClass {
    func log() {
        print("MyProtocol where MyClass")
    }
}

func logByProtocol(_ p: MyProtocol) {
    p.log()
    print("Type of p is: \(type(of: p))")
}

let myGenericClassNumber = MyGenericClass(1)
let myGenericClassString = MyGenericClass("1")
let myClass = MyClass()


myGenericClassNumber.log()//expect "MyGenericClass<Int>"
myGenericClassString.log()//expect "MyGenericClass MyProtocol"
myClass.log()//expect "MyProtocol where MyClass"

logByProtocol(myGenericClassNumber)//expect "MyGenericClass<Int>", BUT "MyGenericClass MyProtocol"
logByProtocol(myGenericClassString)//expect "MyGenericClass MyProtocol"
logByProtocol(myClass)//expect "MyProtocol where MyClass"
```

I expect that `logByProtocol(myGenericClassNumber)` will print `"MyGenericClass<Int>"`, but it prints "MyGenericClass MyProtocol".

It seems that `MyGenericClass<Int>` can't find the original `log()` method while it is done type downcasting to `MyProtocol`.

How to solve this problem to make a `"down"` class can call its original method?

Comment: Solved. Simply add `if p is MyGenericClass<Int> { (p as! MyGenericClass<Int>).log() }`.

Comment: You have to write as many as if else as many generics you would create, like string generic, double generic, float generic, etc. This is not solution, its hack!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because [Swift dynamic dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27) is ignoring this generic constraint:

```
MyGenericClass where T==Int
```

and dispatching call on this extension:

```
extension MyGenericClass: MyProtocol {}
```

Dynamic dispatch I'm talking about is where you have written `logByProtocol(_)` method; which is using dynamic dispatch to call `log()` method.

And why this

```
myGenericClassNumber.log()
```

is working as expected is because it is statically dispatched `log()` method on `MyGenericClass<Int>` object.

Comment: That explains behaviour, but doesn't answer author's question.